# Controlling CSS page breaks when printing in Webkit

Tags: html, css, webkit

I'm attempting to improve the appearance of html documents printed using Webkit, in this case by exerting some control over where page breaks occur.

I'm able to insert page breaks where I need using:

```
page-break-after: always;
```

However, I can't find a way to avoid page breaks being inserted in the middle of items. For example, I have html tables that should not be split in the middle across multiple pages. I had the impression that

```
page-break-inside: avoid;
```

would prevent a page break from being inserted inside the element, but it doesn't seem to be doing anything. My code looks like:

```
.dontsplit { border: 2px solid black; page-break-inside: avoid; }

<table class="dontsplit">
    <tr><td>Some title</td></tr>
    <tr><td><img src="something.jpg"></td></tr>
</table>
```

Despite the page-break-inside: avoid directive I still get the table split between the first and second row into separate pages.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Downloaded a recent binary of wkhtmltopdf http://code.google.com/p/wkhtmltopdf/, and the following seems to work.

```
.dontsplit { border: 2px solid black; page-break-inside: avoid; }

<table>
  <tr><td><div class="dontsplit">Some title</div></td></tr>
  <tr><td><div class="dontsplit"><img src="something.jpg"></div></td></tr>
</table>
```

reference: http://code.google.com/p/wkhtmltopdf/issues/detail?id=9#c21

Prudent to put margin, and padding to zero on the td, and place any on the div, otherwise you'll get "edges" making it over the folds

Comment: Clever! I was almost about to give up. Sadly it doesn't seem to work if you have more than one td in a tr, even if you make them all belong to the class.

Comment: @Myforwik -- if the height of those TD's is different, the splitting seems to default to the shortest div (either that, or the first declared div in the row -- haven't finished experimenting).   The solution that's worked to me is to -- after the fact -- probe each div in a row with javascript and set the heights via jquery to the tallest div.  This approach works well then on .11rc1

Comment: .dontsplit { page-break-inside: avoid; } added to a DIV works in  Firefox v54.x

Answer (score 5):

As cliffordlife states,

```
.dontsplit { border: 2px solid black; page-break-inside: avoid; }
```

will work. But not for firefox. In firefox, what you are going to have to do is check for the height and then add `page-break-after: always;` when it is relevant.

On average, the margin will be 1 inch on top and bottom. So, to measure how many pixels a 10 inch page would consume, I used this:

```
var pageOfPixels;
(function(){
    var d = document.createElement("div");
    d.setAttribute("style", "height:9in;position:absolute;left:0px;top:0px;z-index:-5;");
    document.body.appendChild(d);
    pageOfPixels = $(d).height();
    d.parentNode.removeChild(d);
})();
```

I had a lot of divs each with a lot of paragraphs in them. So what I did was I iterated through them, and then compared the current height of the them on the current page to the pageOfPixels value.

```
var currentPosition = 0;
$('.printDiv').each(function (index, element) {
    var h = $(this).height();
    if (currentPosition + h > pageOfPixels) {
        //add page break
        $('.printDiv').eq(index - 1).css("page-break-after", "always");
        currentPosition = h;
    } else {
        currentPosition += h;
    }
});
```

This worked for me in firefox.

Answer (score 1):

Nevermind: looks like this is a webkit issue:

https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=5097