# When printing page table rows/cells gets split on page break

Tags: css, printing, cells, page-break

I have an table with nested tables in. When I am printing this page, the cells gets split on page break.

Is there any chance that I can control that it should jump onto the next page instead of splitting the middle?

Comment: For webkit based browsers see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1539876/controlling-css-page-breaks-when-printing-in-webkit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have a look at the [page-break-before](http://www.w3schools.com/Css/pr_print_pagebb.asp) css property. For example you can set it to `auto` on each of your cells.

Bur I can't guarantee this will work, each navigator prints a little differently. Firefox is known to have problems printing big tables (more than a page) for example.

Comment: But the default value is 'auto'?

Comment: Like I said, browsers tends to do strange things when printing. I once resolved a similar problem with page-break-before: auto. Maybe with a piece of your html code it will be easier to help.

Answer (score 2):

I have used the following method to keep the contents of a row together on one page:

```
<tr style="page-break-inside: avoid">
```

Unfortunately browser support is limited. Works fine in Internet Explorer 9, but not in Chrome 22 or Firefox 15.

Comment: As of 2016, **this should now work in recent browsers.** Mozilla Developer Network claims "basic support" starting with Chrome 1.0, Firefox 19, IE 8.0, Opera 7.0, and Safari 1.3. (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/page-break-inside) It works fine for me in recent Firefox.