# How to print table headers on multiple pages for Internet Explorer and Google chrome?

Tags: html, css, jsp

I am working on a project in which I have to print data having multiple columns and rows.
I want to print headers on every printing page so that it will be easier to understand with the headers on every page. I know `THEAD` but it supports only Firefox. I want it for IE and chrome. Please help me.

Comment: This > http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7211229/having-google-chrome-repeat-table-headers-on-printed-pages would help you to make it happen.

Answer (score 1):

http://www.evagoras.com/2011/02/10/printing-table-headers-on-every-page/ 
This link helped me to solve it. 
It is running successfully on IE.

```
<style type="text/css" media="print,screen" >
th {
    font-family:Arial;
    color:black;
    background-color:lightgrey;
}
thead {
    display:table-header-group;
}
tbody {
    display:table-row-group;
}
</style>
```

Thanks for all your responses.

Answer (score 0):

Put your headers in an actual `<thead>` element. That seems to work for me in the past. I'm on my phone right now so cannot test it in the specific browsers you mentioned.

#### References

- http://www.quackit.com/html/tags/html_thead_tag.cfm