# how to repeat header row in grid view in each print page in google chrome ??? using asp.net(c#)

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome, gridview

I search a lot to find a solution and now I find great one and I try it and
   found it from https://stackoverflow.com/a/25737442/4542500
   when I try It like that It's work fine

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true"    
CodeFile="Default.aspx.cs"Inherits="_Default" %>
 <!DOCTYPE html>
   <html>
 <body>
  <table class="print t1"> <!-- Delete "t1" class to remove row numbers. -->
  <caption>Print-Friendly Table</caption>
  <thead>
    <tr>
 <th></th>
  <th>Column Header</th>
  <th>Column Header</th>
   <th>Multi-Line<br/>Column<br/>Header</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
  <td></td>
  <td>data</td>
 <td>Multiple<br/>lines of<br/>data</td>
  <td>data</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
 </body>
  </html>
  <style>    

/* THE FOLLOWING CSS IS REQUIRED AND SHOULD NOT BE MODIFIED. */
div.fauxRow {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  width: 100%;
  page-break-inside: avoid;
}
table.fauxRow {border-spacing: 0;}
table.fauxRow > tbody > tr > td {
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}
table.fauxRow > tbody > tr > td > table.print {
  display: inline-table;
  vertical-align: top;
}
table.fauxRow > tbody > tr > td > table.print > caption {caption-side: top;}
.noBreak {
  float: right;
  width: 100%;
  visibility: hidden;
}
.noBreak:before, .noBreak:after {
  display: block;
  content: "";
}
.noBreak:after {margin-top: -594mm;}
.noBreak > div {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  width:100%;
  page-break-inside: avoid;
 }
 /*table.print > thead {white-space: nowrap;}*/ /* Uncomment if line-wrapping   
 causes problems. */
table.print > tbody > tr {page-break-inside: avoid;}
 table.print > tbody > .metricsRow > td {border-top: none !important;}
/* THE FOLLOWING CSS IS REQUIRED, but the values may be adjusted. */
/* NOTE: All size values that can affect an element's height should use the 
 px unit! */
table.fauxRow, table.print {
font-size: 16px;
line-height: 20px;
}
  /* THE FOLLOWING CSS IS OPTIONAL. */
body {counter-reset: t1;} /* Delete to remove row numbers. */
.noBreak .t1 > tbody > tr > :first-child:before {counter-increment: none;} /*   
 Delete to remove row numbers. */
 .t1 > tbody > tr > :first-child:before { /* Delete to remove row numbers. */
  display: block;
  text-align: right;
  counter-increment: t1 1;
 content: counter(t1);
}
  table.fauxRow, table.print {
    font-family: Tahoma, Verdana, Georgia; /* Try to use fonts that don't get    
  bigger when printed. */
margin: 0 auto 0 auto; /* Delete if you don't want table to be centered. */
}
table.print {border-spacing: 0;}
table.print > * > tr > * {
  border-right: 2px solid black;
  border-bottom: 2px solid black;
  padding: 0 5px 0 5px;
}
table.print > * > :first-child > * {border-top: 2px solid black;}
table.print > thead ~ * > :first-child > *, table.print > tbody ~ * > :first-  
child > * {border-top: none;}
table.print > * > tr > :first-child {border-left: 2px solid black;}
table.print > thead {vertical-align: bottom;}
table.print > thead > .borderRow > th {border-bottom: none;}
table.print > tbody {vertical-align: top;}
table.print > caption {font-weight: bold;}
</style>
<script>

   (function () { // THIS FUNCTION IS NOT REQUIRED. It just adds table rows   
  for testing purposes.
   var rowCount = 100
  , tbod = document.querySelector("table.print > tbody")
  , row = tbod.rows[0];
 for (; --rowCount; tbod.appendChild(row.cloneNode(true)));
  })();
   function () { // THIS FUNCTION IS REQUIRED.
    if (/Firefox|MSIE/i.test(navigator.userAgent))
     var formatForPrint = function (table) {
     var noBreak = document.createElement("div")
  , noBreakTable = 
   noBreak.appendChild(document.createElement("div"))
  .appendChild(table.cloneNode())
   , tableParent = table.parentNode
   , tableParts = table.children
   , partCount = tableParts.length
   , partNum = 0
   , cell = table.querySelector("tbody > tr > td");
   noBreak.className = "noBreak";
    for (; partNum < partCount; partNum++) {
   if (!/tbody/i.test(tableParts[partNum].tagName))
  noBreakTable.appendChild(tableParts[partNum].cloneNode(true));
     }
   if (cell) {            
    noBreakTable.appendChild(cell.parentNode.parentNode.cloneNode())
  .appendChild(cell.parentNode.cloneNode(true));
    if (!table.tHead) {
    var borderRow = document.createElement("tr");
    borderRow.appendChild(document.createElement("th")).colSpan = "1000";
    borderRow.className = "borderRow";
   table.insertBefore(document.createElement("thead"),  
   table.tBodies[0]).appendChild(borderRow);
     }
    }
    tableParent.insertBefore(document.createElement("div"),   
    table).style.paddingTop = ".009px";
      tableParent.insertBefore(noBreak, table);
   };
    else
   var formatForPrint = function (table) {
   var tableParent = table.parentNode
   , cell = table.querySelector("tbody > tr > td");
   if (cell) {
   var topFauxRow = document.createElement("table")
  , fauxRowTable =   
    topFauxRow.insertRow(0).insertCell(0).appendChild(table.cloneNode())
    , colgroup = fauxRowTable.appendChild(document.createElement("colgroup"))
    , headerHider = document.createElement("div")
    , metricsRow = document.createElement("tr")
    , cells = cell.parentNode.cells
    , cellNum = cells.length
    , colCount = 0
    , tbods = table.tBodies
    , tbodCount = tbods.length
    , tbodNum = 0
    , tbod = tbods[0];
   for (; cellNum--; colCount += cells[cellNum].colSpan);
    for (cellNum = colCount; cellNum--;  
  metricsRow.appendChild(document.createElement("td")).style.padding = 0);
 cells = metricsRow.cells;
  tbod.insertBefore(metricsRow, tbod.firstChild);
  for (; ++cellNum < colCount;    
 colgroup.appendChild(document.createElement("col")).style.width =   
  cells[cellNum].offsetWidth + "px");
  var borderWidth = metricsRow.offsetHeight;
 metricsRow.className = "metricsRow";
 borderWidth -= metricsRow.offsetHeight;
 tbod.removeChild(metricsRow);
 tableParent.insertBefore(topFauxRow, table).className = "fauxRow";
 if (table.tHead)
 fauxRowTable.appendChild(table.tHead);
 var fauxRow = topFauxRow.cloneNode(true)
 , fauxRowCell = fauxRow.rows[0].cells[0];
  fauxRowCell.insertBefore(headerHider,  
  fauxRowCell.firstChild).style.marginBottom = -fauxRowTable.offsetHeight -    
   borderWidth + "px";
  if (table.caption)
  fauxRowTable.insertBefore(table.caption, fauxRowTable.firstChild);
 if (tbod.rows[0])                      
 fauxRowTable.appendChild(tbod.cloneNode()).appendChild(tbod.rows[0]);
 tbod = tbods[tbodNum];
 rows = tbod.rows;
 for (; rows[0]; tableParent.insertBefore(fauxRow.cloneNode(true),   
 table).rows[0].cells[0].children[1].appendChild
 (tbod.cloneNode()).appendChild(rows[0]));
  }
  tableParent.removeChild(table);
  }
else
 tableParent.insertBefore(document.createElement("div"),   
  table).appendChild(table).parentNode.className = "fauxRow";
   };
   var tables = document.body.querySelectorAll("table.print")
  , tableNum = tables.length;
 for (; tableNum--; formatForPrint(tables[tableNum]));
})();
 </script>

but when I apply my Grid view and try to print It print the grid view it print the grid view but without repeating the grid view header  in each page  plus I don't know how to transfer my grid view to table like to transfer the grid view to table and the item template to column in <tr> and <td> as the code above
```

any one can told me whats the issue here and how to transfer the grid view to table 
   my code :

```
   <body>
  <form id="form1" runat="server">
  <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AllowPaging="false"      
  EnableSortingAndPagingCallbacks="false" BackColor="White"     
 BorderColor="#999999" 
         ViewStateMode="Enabled" width="713px"CellPadding="3"   
 HorizontalAlign="Center" AllowSorting="True"
   BorderStyle="Solid" BorderWidth="1px" ForeColor="Black"  
 GridLines="Vertical" AutoGenerateColumns="False" PageSize="20"   
 Height="16px" >
   <Columns>
  <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="الرصيد">
  <ItemTemplate>
  <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblTotal" Text=""></asp:Label>
  </ItemTemplate>
  </asp:TemplateField>
  <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="مدين">
  <ItemTemplate>
  <div style="padding:0 0 5px 0"> <asp:Label ID="debit" runat="server"   
  Text='<%# (Eval("stat_flag").ToString() =="d" ) ? string.Format(" 
    {0:0.000}",float.Parse(Eval("stat_amount").ToString())): "0.00" %>'> 
     </asp:Label></div>
  <div><asp:Label ID="lblGrandTotal" runat="server" /></div>
  </ItemTemplate>
   <FooterTemplate>
  <asp:Label ID="totallblDebAmount" runat="server" />
   </FooterTemplate>   
   </asp:TemplateField>
   <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="دائن">
   <ItemTemplate>
    <div style="padding:0 0 5px 0"><asp:Label ID="credit" runat="server" 
   Text='<%# (Eval("stat_flag").ToString() =="c" ) ? string.Format("  
    {0:0.000}",float.Parse(Eval("stat_amount").ToString())): "0.00" %>'>  
   </asp:Label></div>
   </ItemTemplate>
  <FooterTemplate>
 <asp:Label ID="totallblCredAmount" runat="server" />
 </FooterTemplate>   
 </asp:TemplateField>
   <asp:BoundField  DataField="stat_desc" HeaderText="البيان" ItemStyle-Font- 
 Size="Small">
  <ItemStyle Font-Size="Small"></ItemStyle>
  </asp:BoundField>
  <asp:BoundField  DataField="serial" 
   HeaderText=" رقم السند " ItemStyle-Font Size="Small">
  <ItemStyle Font-Size="Small"></ItemStyle>
    </asp:BoundField>
     <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="التاريخ">
     <ItemTemplate>
    <asp:Label ID="date" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("stat_date" ,"  
     {0:dd/MM/yyyy}" )%>'> ></asp:Label>
     </ItemTemplate>
     </asp:TemplateField>
     </Columns>
   <FooterStyle BackColor="#336699" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White"   
  HorizontalAlign="right" />
  <RowStyle BorderColor="Black" BorderStyle="Solid" BorderWidth="1px" />                           
 <HeaderStyle BackColor="#aaaaaa" Font-Bold="True" HorizontalAlign="Center" 
       VerticalAlign="Middle" ForeColor="Black" BorderColor="Black"   
    BorderStyle="Solid" BorderWidth="1px"/>
   <PagerStyle BackColor="#999999" ForeColor="Blue" HorizontalAlign="Left"  
  Font-Bold="True" 
   Font-Underline="False" BorderStyle="Solid" BorderWidth="1px"  
   BorderColor="#666666" />
   </asp:GridView>
   </body>
  </html>
  <style>

 /*THE FoLOWING CSS IS REQUIRED AND SHOULD NOT BE MODIFIED. */
   div.fauxRow {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  width: 100%;
  page-break-inside: avoid;
}
table.fauxRow {border-spacing: 0;}
table.fauxRow > tbody > tr > td {
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}
table.fauxRow > tbody > tr > td > table.print {
  display: inline-table;
  vertical-align: top;
}
table.fauxRow > tbody > tr > td > table.print > caption {caption-side: top;}
.noBreak {
  float: right;
  width: 100%;
  visibility: hidden;
}
.noBreak:before, .noBreak:after {
  display: block;
  content: "";
}
.noBreak:after {margin-top: -594mm;}
.noBreak > div {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  width:100%;
  page-break-inside: avoid;
}
/*table.print > thead {white-space: nowrap;}*/ /* Uncomment if line-wrapping  
causes problems. */
table.print > tbody > tr {page-break-inside: avoid;}
table.print > tbody > .metricsRow > td {border-top: none !important;}
   /* THE FOLLOWING CSS IS REQUIRED, but the values may be adjusted. */
     /* NOTE: All size values that can affect an element's height should use 
 the px unit! */
table.fauxRow, table.print {
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 20px;
}

   /* THE FOLLOWING CSS IS OPTIONAL. */
   body {counter-reset: t1;} /* Delete to remove row numbers. */
.noBreak .t1 > tbody > tr > :first-child:before {counter-increment: none;} /* 
 Delete to remove row numbers. */
.t1 > tbody > tr > :first-child:before { /* Delete to remove row numbers. */
  display: block;
  text-align: right;
  counter-increment: t1 1;
  content: counter(t1);
}
table.fauxRow, table.print {
  font-family: Tahoma, Verdana, Georgia; /* Try to use fonts that don't get  
 bigger when printed. */
  margin: 0 auto 0 auto; /* Delete if you don't want table to be centered. */
}
table.print {border-spacing: 0;}
table.print > * > tr > * {
  border-right: 2px solid black;
  border-bottom: 2px solid black;
  padding: 0 5px 0 5px;
}
table.print > * > :first-child > * {border-top: 2px solid black;}
table.print > thead ~ * > :first-child > *, table.print > tbody ~ * > :first-
 child > * {border-top: none;}
table.print > * > tr > :first-child {border-left: 2px solid black;}
table.print > thead {vertical-align: bottom;}
table.print > thead > .borderRow > th {border-bottom: none;}
table.print > tbody {vertical-align: top;}
table.print > caption {font-weight: bold;}
 </style>
 <script>

  (function () { // THIS FUNCTION IS REQUIRED.
    if (/Firefox|MSIE/i.test(navigator.userAgent))
     var formatForPrint = function (table) {
   var noBreak = document.createElement("div")
   , noBreakTable =       
    noBreak.appendChild(document.createElement("div")).
    appendChild(table.cloneNode())
   , tableParent = table.parentNode
   , tableParts = table.children
   , partCount = tableParts.length
   , partNum = 0
    , cell = table.querySelector("tbody > tr > td");
    noBreak.className = "noBreak";
  for (; partNum < partCount; partNum++) {
    if (!/tbody/i.test(tableParts[partNum].tagName))                     
   noBreakTable.appendChild(tableParts[partNum].cloneNode(true));
  }
  if (cell) {                   
   noBreakTable.appendChild(cell.parentNode.parentNode.cloneNode()).
  appendChild(.appendChild(cell.parentNode.cloneNode(true));
 if (!table.tHead) {
  var borderRow = document.createElement("tr");                        
  borderRow.appendChild(document.createElement("th")).colSpan = "1000";
  borderRow.className = "borderRow";
  table.insertBefore(document.createElement("thead"),          
   table.tBodies[0]).appendChild(borderRow);
  }
    }
  tableParent.insertBefore(document.createElement("div"), 
    table).style.paddingTop = ".009px";
    tableParent.insertBefore(noBreak, table);
    };
   else
   var formatForPrint = function (table) {
   var tableParent = table.parentNode
 , cell = table.querySelector("tbody > tr > td");
    if (cell) {
    var topFauxRow = document.createElement("table")
  , fauxRowTable = 
  topFauxRow.insertRow(0).insertCell(0).appendChild(table.cloneNode())
 , colgroup = fauxRowTable.appendChild(document.createElement("colgroup"))
 , headerHider = document.createElement("div")
 , metricsRow = document.createElement("tr")
 , cells = cell.parentNode.cells
 , cellNum = cells.length
 , colCount = 0
 , tbods = table.tBodies
 , tbodCount = tbods.length
 , tbodNum = 0
 , tbod = tbods[0];
 for (; cellNum--; colCount += cells[cellNum].colSpan);
 for (cellNum = colCount; cellNum--; 
  metricsRow.appendChild(document.createElement("td")).style.padding = 0);
    cells = metricsRow.cells;
  tbod.insertBefore(metricsRow, tbod.firstChild);
   for (; ++cellNum < colCount;     
  colgroup.appendChild(document.createElement("col")).style.width =   
  cells[cellNum].offsetWidth + "px");
  var borderWidth = metricsRow.offsetHeight;
  metricsRow.className = "metricsRow";
  borderWidth -= metricsRow.offsetHeight;
 tbod.removeChild(metricsRow);
  tableParent.insertBefore(topFauxRow, table).className = "fauxRow";
   if (table.tHead)
   fauxRowTable.appendChild(table.tHead);
  var fauxRow = topFauxRow.cloneNode(true)
 , fauxRowCell = fauxRow.rows[0].cells[0];
  fauxRowCell.insertBefore(headerHider, 
   fauxRowCell.firstChild).style.marginBottom = -fauxRowTable.offsetHeight - 
    borderWidth + "px";
  if (table.caption)
  fauxRowTable.insertBefore(table.caption, fauxRowTable.firstChild);
  if (tbod.rows[0])                 
  fauxRowTable.appendChild(tbod.cloneNode()).appendChild(tbod.rows[0]);
  for (; tbodNum < tbodCount; tbodNum++) {
  tbod = tbods[tbodNum];
  rows = tbod.rows;
  for (; rows[0]; tableParent.insertBefore(fauxRow.cloneNode(true), 
   table).rows[0].cells[0].children[1].appendChild(tbod.cloneNode()).
    appendChild(rows[0]));
  }
 tableParent.removeChild(table);
    }
  else
 tableParent.insertBefore(document.createElement("div"),   
 table).appendChild(table).parentNode.className = "fauxRow";
    };
 var tables = document.body.querySelectorAll("table.print")
 , tableNum = tables.length;
  for (; tableNum--; formatForPrint(tables[tableNum]));
  })();
  </script>
   </form>
```