# Printing Tables with Bootstrap W/ Proper Page Breaks

Tags: html, css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to make a table printable, specifically never have it break a `<td>` entry in half, while maintaining proper borders. I am trying this:

```
    @media print {
        table.print-friendly tr td, table.print-friendly tr th {
            page-break-inside: avoid;
        }
    }
```

However, this still causes a problem where the table data is missing upper or lower margins. Actually, I am not sure it does anything, because without it, the table misses the last margin on the first page. Easier to explain with an image here:

[image]

[Plnkr here.](http://plnkr.co/edit/RPAoz1Lsi35yRLJBttwh?p=preview) Everything relevant is in index.html - I think you need to copy it to notepad and run locally to test printing. Note that the only relevant things in that code are the `<style>` definitions and the table classes.

To summarize - my goal is to make the table break properly AND maintain margins on print.

Comment: [Look here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25737442/2759272) to see how to make a table print correctly in Chrome or any other browser. I haven't looked into Chrome's printing capabilities recently so it's possible there are simpler solutions available, but I doubt it. For page margins, you might want to look into the [@page rule](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@page). In your case, it would probably look something like this: `@page {margin-left: 200px;}`

Comment: Thanks, I will look at your answer there in detail and let you know if it works for me. Upvoted your linked answer.