# Make chrome put table header at the top of each page for long printed table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a really long table that when printed, spans several pages.

Currently, when printing the table, the header row only appears at the very top of the table and not at the top of each page.

How can I make the browser (specifically chrome) print a "sticky" table header at the top of every printed page?

My html:

```
<table>
  <!--header-->
  <tr>
    <td>Col 1</td>
    <td>Col 2</td>
    <td>Col 3</td>
    <td>Col 4</td>
  </tr>

  <!--body-->
  <tr>
    <td>Row 1</td>
    <td>Row 1</td>
    <td>Row 1</td>
    <td>Row 1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Row 2</td>
    <td>Row 2</td>
    <td>Row 2</td>
    <td>Row 2</td>
  </tr>
  . . . . . .
  <tr>
    <td>Row nth</td>
    <td>Row nth</td>
    <td>Row nth</td>
    <td>Row nth</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: are you saying that you have a really long table that when printed, spans several pages and you would like to print a "sticky" header for the table at the top of every printed page?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Having Google Chrome repeat table headers on printed pages](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7211229/having-google-chrome-repeat-table-headers-on-printed-pages)

Comment: yes exactly @DelightedD0D ..............

Comment: I don't know why some one is down vote me

Comment: @Kushan I downvoted you, but to be fair, when I did so, your answer was wrong and didnt really do anything different except to use `th`. You have since changed it to incorporate the correct answer and I have removed the downvote :)

Answer (score 1):

To make this work properly, just make sure you are using the `<thead>` and `<tbody>` tags in your html like the below. With those elements in place, every major browser I know of will know how to handle the page breaks automatically:

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Col 1</th>
      <th>Col 2</th>
      <th>Col 3</th>
      <th>Col 4</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Row 1</td>
      <td>Row 1</td>
      <td>Row 1</td>
      <td>Row 1</td>
    </tr>

    ....

  </tbody>
</table>
```

[image]

Comment: @nzrnfourtwenty yep, that screenshot is from chrome. Is this not working on your machine? If not, what version of chrome are you running and on what operating system?

Comment: @nzrnfourtwenty can you make a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) and show me your actual html?