# How to style a title in a head (html)

Tags: javascript, html, css

```
title {
  display: block;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-family: 'Helvetica';
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

What i wanted to do is to print multiple pages in html that include the title and a page number inside the header and footer of every page respectively.

1. How to style a title in a head or is there any other way to print a header on every printed page.
2. How to hide the date but enable the title and a page number on every printed page (after enabling the header and footer in a print preview)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use HTML to print header and footer on every printed page of a document?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1360869/how-to-use-html-to-print-header-and-footer-on-every-printed-page-of-a-document)

Comment: It doesnt work on chrome bro. Only the first page will appears the "unclassifed" word

Comment: Still a dupe though. If someone has an better answer than the ones there, he should add it there.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Make chrome put table header at the top of each page for long printed table](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40098940/make-chrome-put-table-header-at-the-top-of-each-page-for-long-printed-table)

Answer (score 0):

In Firefox IIUC you can't style it, but you can tweak the output, for example to remove all the titles, page numbers etc:

```
ref("print.print_headerleft", "");
pref("print.print_headercenter", "");
pref("print.print_headerright", "");
pref("print.print_footerleft", "");
pref("print.print_footercenter", "");
pref("print.print_footerright", "");
```

Comment: Should be put under css or javascript?