# Table row splits across two pages (print media)

Tags: html, css, printing, printing-web-page

I have a table which is OK in web pages, but when printing my table (<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>p</kbd>) it breaks not the way I want. The last row of the first page splits with the part of the row on the first page and the other part of the row on the second page. So, is there any way to overcome the problem, the rows can have different content and size. I also tried this properties

```
 page-break-before/after: auto. page-break-inside:avoid;
```

but with no result. Is there any way to break the table and move the part of the table to the next page without splitting the last row into two parts for print media? Any help will be appreciated.

[image]

> table,th,td
>       {
>       border:1px solid black;
>       border-collapse:collapse;
>       }
>       th,td
>       {
>       padding:5px;
>       }
>
> ```
> </style>
> </head>
> <body>
> <table style="width:100%;">
> <tr>
>   <th><span>Firstname</span></th>
>   <th><span>Lastname</span></th>      
>   <th><span>Points</span></th>
> </tr>
> <tr>
>   <td><span>Jill</span></td>
>   <td><span>Smith</span></td>     
>   <td><span>50</span></td>
> </tr>
> <tr>
>   <td><span>Eve</span></td>
>   <td><span>Jackson</span></td>       
>   <td><span>94</span></td>
> </tr>
> <tr>
>   <td><span>John</span></td>
>   <td><span>Doe</span></td>       
>   <td><span>80</span></td>
> </tr>
>    /*here I have many <tr> elements*/
> </table>
>
> </body>
> </html>
> ```

Answer (score 3):

If I understand correctly, you want your table to break only between rows and not within them. You can accomplish this in Firefox and Internet Explorer with the following css rule:

```
tr {page-break-inside: avoid;}
```

Unfortunately, that doesn't work in other popular browsers, such as Chrome.

As has been suggested, you can prevent page breaks within the content of an individual cell by wrapping it in a div that has "page-break-inside: avoid;" set on it, but if the content height varies within the row, you'll still end up with parts of the row on two different pages.

If you *really* want to solve this problem and are willing to throw some javascript at it, [I have posted a solution here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7211229/having-google-chrome-repeat-table-headers-on-printed-pages/25737442#25737442) that should do the trick.

Comment: @delphirules If you want a solution that works in Webkit browsers such as Chrome, Safari, and Opera, then check the link at the bottom of my post.

Answer (score 0):

You can request a page break, which will be invisible on the screen, but will force the element to a new page when you print.  But the rules are more subtle than you might expect.

The *CSS* property `page-break-before:always` can only by applied to a **block** element.  Not an **inline**, or anything odd like a **table-row** or a **list-item**.  So do not style the row or cell, nor even a `<tbody>` or a `<br/>`.  And it cannot be an element that the browser is allowed to omit, so you cannot just throw in an empty `<div>` with the style on it.  One has to add a `<div>` or `<p>` around the first cell contents, for instance, to give the style.

Likewise `page-break-after:always` can be applied to something similar at the end of the previous row.  I find this totally annoying, as what I always want to protect is a row, or a  grouping.

Some browsers may also want you to change the style of your table to `page-break-inside:auto`, as the default style for a table is often already `page-break-before:avoid`.

Since it is the default style, *adding it does not help*.  The browser is already avoiding breaking your table as much as it is willing to.  But failing to remove it easily makes the other options useless, especially in Chrome.