# Print subtotals on each page with HTML/CSS/JS maybe XSLT?

Tags: html, css, printing, html-table

I would like to use the open standards for printing reports, this report would need to have subtotals on the end of each page.

The thread [Use of XSL-FO, CSS3 instead of CSS2 to create Paginated documents like PDF?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10641667/why-use-xsl-fo-instead-of-css2-for-transform-html-into-good-pdf) suggest that HTML with CSS3 is the way to go.

Now the problem that I get is determining with HTML or with CSS or with JS the place where the A4 page will be filled so that the pagebreak would appear.

There are the CSS page break selectors:

```
page-break-before: always | avoid — always/avoid page breaks before the item
page-break-after: always | avoid — always/avoid page breaks after the item
page-break-inside: always | avoid — always/avoid page breaks in the middle of the item
```

But these aren't really usefull for the purpose of subtotals on each pages as I don't know when would the page fill up so that I could place a tag there with such CSS applied to it.

The HTML TABLE tag suppors somekind of table header and footer that sounds promising:

> Table rows may be grouped into a table head, table foot, and one or
>   more table body sections, using the THEAD, TFOOT and TBODY elements,
>   respectively. This division enables user agents to support scrolling
>   of table bodies independently of the table head and foot. When long
>   tables are printed, the table head and foot information may be
>   repeated on each page that contains table data.

```
<TABLE>
<THEAD>
     <TR> ...header information...
</THEAD>
<TFOOT>
     <TR> ...footer information...
</TFOOT>
<TBODY>
     <TR> ...first row of block one data...
     <TR> ...second row of block one data...
</TBODY>
<TBODY>
     <TR> ...first row of block two data...
     <TR> ...second row of block two data...
     <TR> ...third row of block two data...
</TBODY>
</TABLE>
```

But this again isn't very usefull as the same footers would appear on all pages with the same subtotals and not for each page. Otherwise I should make a table with different TFOOTs and TBODYs, a static structure according to when the page is filled... but I can't get that kind of information, only the number of rows is that I could specify when building the HTML table. I dont see the way to create them as the A4 size would fit them.

I don't know, maybe XSLT would help here or javascript? Is there an open standard CSS3, HTML5 or other solution for this problem that I'm not aware of? If no, anyone knows a workaround, examples for solving this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This can be done with plain old JavaScript, as demonstrated by the code below.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>
    <table class="data">
      <caption><b>MY TABLE</b></caption>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Col 1</th><th>Col 2</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr><td>1<td>1<tr><td>0<td>99<tr><td>1<td>1<tr><td>0<td>99<tr><td>1<td>1<tr><td>0<td>99
        <tr><td>2<td>9<tr><td>2<td>88<tr><td>2<td>0<tr><td>2<td>88<tr><td>2<td>0<tr><td>2<td>88
        <tr><td>3<td>1<tr><td>4<td>77<tr><td>3<td>1<tr><td>4<td>77<tr><td>3<td>1<tr><td>4<td>77
        <tr><td>4<td>8<tr><td>6<td>66<tr><td>4<td>1<tr><td>6<td>66<tr><td>4<td>1<tr><td>6<td>66
        <tr><td>5<td>1<tr><td>8<td>55<tr><td>5<td>1<tr><td>8<td>55<tr><td>5<td>1<tr><td>8<td>55
        <tr><td>6<td>7<tr><td>0<td>44<tr><td>6<td>2<tr><td>0<td>44<tr><td>6<td>2<tr><td>0<td>44
        <tr><td>7<td>1<tr><td>2<td>33<tr><td>7<td>1<tr><td>2<td>33<tr><td>7<td>1<tr><td>2<td>33
        <tr><td>8<td>6<tr><td>4<td>22<tr><td>8<td>3<tr><td>4<td>22<tr><td>8<td>3<tr><td>4<td>22
        <tr><td>9<td>1<tr><td>6<td>11<tr><td>9<td>1<tr><td>6<td>11<tr><td>9<td>1<tr><td>6<td>11
        <tr><td>1<td>0<tr><td>0<td>99<tr><td>1<td>4<tr><td>0<td>99<tr><td>1<td>4<tr><td>0<td>99
        <tr><td>2<td>1<tr><td>2<td>88<tr><td>2<td>1<tr><td>2<td>88<tr><td>2<td>1<tr><td>2<td>88
        <tr><td>3<td>1<tr><td>4<td>77<tr><td>3<td>1<tr><td>4<td>77<tr><td>3<td>1<tr><td>4<td>77
        <tr><td>4<td>5<tr><td>6<td>66<tr><td>4<td>5<tr><td>6<td>66<tr><td>4<td>5<tr><td>6<td>66
        <tr><td>5<td>1<tr><td>8<td>55<tr><td>5<td>1<tr><td>8<td>55<tr><td>5<td>1<tr><td>8<td>55
        <tr><td>6<td>4<tr><td>0<td>44<tr><td>6<td>6<tr><td>0<td>44<tr><td>6<td>6<tr><td>0<td>44
        <tr><td>7<td>1<tr><td>2<td>33<tr><td>7<td>1<tr><td>2<td>33<tr><td>7<td>1<tr><td>2<td>33
        <tr><td>8<td>3<tr><td>4<td>22<tr><td>8<td>7<tr><td>4<td>22<tr><td>8<td>7<tr><td>4<td>22
        <tr><td>9<td>1<tr><td>6<td>11<tr><td>9<td>1<tr><td>6<td>11<tr><td>9<td>1<tr><td>6<td>11
        <tr><td>1<td>2<tr><td>0<td>99<tr><td>1<td>8<tr><td>0<td>99<tr><td>1<td>8<tr><td>0<td>99
        <tr><td>2<td>1<tr><td>2<td>88<tr><td>2<td>1<tr><td>2<td>88<tr><td>2<td>1<tr><td>2<td>88
        <tr><td>3<td>0<tr><td>4<td>77<tr><td>3<td>9<tr><td>4<td>77<tr><td>3<td>9<tr><td>4<td>77
        <tr><td>4<td>1<tr><td>6<td>66<tr><td>4<td>1<tr><td>6<td>66<tr><td>4<td>1<tr><td>6<td>66
        <tr><td>5<td>1<tr><td>8<td>55<tr><td>5<td>0<tr><td>8<td>55<tr><td>5<td>0<tr><td>8<td>55
        <tr><td>6<td>1<tr><td>0<td>44<tr><td>6<td>1<tr><td>0<td>44<tr><td>6<td>1<tr><td>0<td>44
        <tr><td>7<td>0<tr><td>2<td>33<tr><td>7<td>1<tr><td>2<td>33<tr><td>7<td>1<tr><td>2<td>33
        <tr><td>8<td>1<tr><td>4<td>22<tr><td>8<td>1<tr><td>4<td>22<tr><td>8<td>1<tr><td>4<td>22
        <tr><td>9<td>0<tr><td>6<td>11<tr><td>9<td>2<tr><td>6<td>11<tr><td>9<td>2<tr><td>6<td>11
        <tr><!--Use this row for on-screen totals if needed; otherwise, leave it empty.-->
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </body>
</html>

<style>
  @media screen {
    .print {
      display: none; /*Prevents print version of table from showing on screen*/
    }
  }
  @media print {
    .data {
      display: none; /*Prevents screen version of table from showing in print*/
    }
    .print {
      display: block;
    }
    .print > .data {
      display: inline-table; /*Prevents page breaks better than page-break-inside: avoid;*/
      vertical-align: top;
    }
    /*The following rule makes rows opaque in IE even if background colors are disabled.*/
    .print.fixIE > .data > thead > tr > th:after,
    .print.fixIE > .data > tbody > tr:first-child > td:after {
      display: block;
      border-bottom: 18pt solid white; /*Border-width = line-height*/
      margin-top: -18pt; /*Negative line-height*/
      margin-right: -.5em; /*Negative td padding-right*/
      margin-left: -.5em; /*Negative td padding-left*/
      content: "";
    }
    .overlap {
      margin-bottom: -20pt; /*Negative row height (including borders)*/
    }
  }
  .data {
    table-layout: fixed; /*Columns must have fixed widths! Set with <col>s, if needed.*/
    width: 100%;
    border-spacing: 0;
    white-space: nowrap;
    font-size: 12pt;
    line-height: 18pt; /*If you change this, other CSS values must also be changed!*/
    border-right: 1pt solid black;
  }
  .data > thead > tr > th {
    border-top: 1pt solid black;
    border-left: 1pt solid black;
    background: white;
    padding: 0 .5em 0 .5em;
  }
  .data > tbody > tr > td {
    border-top: 1pt solid black; /*If you change this, .overlap must also be changed!*/
    border-left: 1pt solid black;
    background: white;
    padding: 0 .5em 0 .5em; /*If you change this, other CSS values must also be changed!*/
  }
  .data > tbody > tr:last-child > td {
    border-bottom: 1pt solid black; /*If you change this, .overlap must also be changed!*/
  }
  .data > tbody {
    text-align: right;
  }
</style>

<script>
  //This function takes two arguments:
  //1) a reference to a table element
  //2) an array of column indexes indicating which columns have numbers to be totalled.
  function printSubtotals(table, columns) {
    var
      tbody = table.tBodies[0],
      row = tbody.rows[0];
    if(!row)
      return;
    var cellCount = row.cells.length;
    if(!cellCount)
      return;
    var
      subtotals = [],
      rows = table.rows,
      thead = table.tHead,
      caption = table.querySelector('caption'),
      colgroup = table.querySelector('colgroup'),
      emptyTable = table.cloneNode(false),
      emptyRow = row.cloneNode(true),
      printDiv = document.createElement('div'),
      overlap = document.createElement('div'),
      subtotalCount = columns.length,
      rowCount = rows.length - 1,
      cells, subtotalCells, i, r;
    if(colgroup && colgroup.parentNode === table)
      emptyTable.appendChild(colgroup.cloneNode(true));
    emptyTable.appendChild(tbody.cloneNode(false));
    printDiv.className = /MSIE /.test(navigator.userAgent) ? 'print fixIE' : 'print';
    overlap.className = 'overlap';
    for(i = subtotalCount; i--; subtotals.push(0));
    for(i = cellCount; i--; emptyRow.cells[i].innerHTML = '');
    for(r = row.rowIndex; r < rowCount; r++) {
      printDiv.appendChild(overlap.cloneNode(true));
      tbody = printDiv.appendChild(emptyTable.cloneNode(true)).tBodies[0];
      cells = tbody.appendChild(rows[r].cloneNode(true)).cells;
      subtotalCells = tbody.appendChild(emptyRow.cloneNode(true)).cells;
      for(i = subtotalCount; i--;) {
        subtotals[i] += parseFloat(cells[columns[i]].innerHTML);
        subtotalCells[columns[i]].innerHTML = '<b>Total: ' + subtotals[i] + '</b>';
      }
    }
    printDiv.removeChild(printDiv.children[0]);
    tbody = printDiv.children[0].tBodies[0];
    if(caption && caption.parentNode === table)
      tbody.parentNode.insertBefore(caption.cloneNode(true), tbody);
    if(thead)
      tbody.parentNode.insertBefore(thead.cloneNode(true), tbody);
    table.parentNode.insertBefore(printDiv, table);
  }

  printSubtotals(document.querySelector('.data'), [0,1]);
</script>
```

What the Javascript function does is create a print-only version of the table in which every row has a hidden subtotals row attached to it. The subtotals row is covered up by the next row, so it's only visible if the next row gets bumped to the next page, or it's the last row in the table. This should work in just about any browser regardless of paper size. It may seem inefficient, but the perceived performance hit is negligible since the print table doesn't render on page load. Still, I wouldn't recommend this technique for tables with many thousands of rows.

Note that the above code is just a proof-of-concept, and as such, is not particularly robust. A few things that I know will break it are:

- empty cells in data columns
- non-numeric values in data columns
- multi-line content in tbody cells
- varying cell count in tbody rows (e.g. some have colspans and others don't)
- letting cell content determine column width
- changing line-height or border-width without changing other, related CSS values

Some of these things are doable with the right modifications to the JavaScript and CSS.

Comment: The JS code snippet solving this would be interesting to see. Pointing to a working lib for this or jsfiddle example would be appreciated.

Comment: My original answer wouldn't have worked in Chrome and other WebKit browsers, so I rewrote it.