# No page breaks inside a tall row

Tags: html, css, html-table

I want my table to contain no page breaks inside its rows. Here is my code, but it doesn't work (it will still contain a page break when you print it). Please advise

```
<style type="text/css">
tr, td { page-break-inside:avoid; page-break-after:auto }
</style>
<table border=1>
<tr>
<th>1</th>
<th>2</th>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>
One<br>One<br>One<br>One<br>One<br>One<br>One<br>
One<br>One<br>One<br>One<br>One<br>One<br>One<br>
One<br>One<br>One<br>One<br>One<br>One<br>One<br>
One<br>One<br>One<br>One<br>One<br>One<br>One<br>
One<br>One<br>One<br>One<br>One<br>One<br>One<br>
</td>
<td>Two</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>
One<br>One<br>One<br>One<br>One<br>One<br>One<br>
One<br>One<br>One<br>One<br>One<br>One<br>One<br>
One<br>One<br>One<br>One<br>One<br>One<br>One<br>
One<br>One<br>One<br>One<br>One<br>One<br>One<br>
One<br>One<br>One<br>One<br>One<br>One<br>One<br>
</td>
<td>Two</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it turns out what I was doing was correct. However, I was using Google Chrome, which apparently has problems with handling page breaks inside tables.

The same exact code works fine in (brace yourself) Internet Explorer! Surprisingly, IE is better in one thing that FF/Chrome.

Answer (score 0):

That table easily extends past the 8x11" paper.  In this case, it is simply easier to wrap your tables like so

```
<table border=1>
<tr>
<th>1</th>
<th>2</th>
<th>3</th>
<th>4</th>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>
One<br>One<br>One<br>One<br>One<br>One<br>One<br>
One<br>One<br>One<br>One<br>One<br>One<br>One<br>
One<br>One<br>One<br>One<br>One<br>One<br>One<br>
One<br>One<br>One<br>One<br>One<br>One<br>One<br>
One<br>One<br>One<br>One<br>One<br>One<br>One<br>
</td>
<td>Two</td>
<!--Third Row-->
<td>
One<br>One<br>One<br>One<br>One<br>One<br>One<br>
One<br>One<br>One<br>One<br>One<br>One<br>One<br>
One<br>One<br>One<br>One<br>One<br>One<br>One<br>
One<br>One<br>One<br>One<br>One<br>One<br>One<br>
One<br>One<br>One<br>One<br>One<br>One<br>One<br>
</td>
<td>Two</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

[Plunker for reference](http://plnkr.co/edit/KMjn5hZ9pxdEXeraVyI1?p=preview)

Comment: Thanks but you are not answering the question. Obviously, the code here is a dummy code, not the real thing I'm working on. Assume I cannot reformat the tables, I just want them to not break inside a cell in print view.

Comment: If your second TD is going to be that long then it's not going to be very straight forward.  Most browsers render tables a certain way.  Take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1539876/controlling-css-page-breaks-when-printing-in-webkit