# CSS3 Page break for printing not breaking at random spots

Tags: html, css

I have been trying to figure this out for awhile now and I have not been able to get this issue fixed. I am trying to figure out if this is a known issue or I am simply doing something wrong! :/

I am trying to get the page to break into a new page (when printing) on the last `<h2>` of the page. However it seems that it breaks after the first `<h2>` every time even though it shouldn't break until the last `<h2>` that fits on the page.

CSS Code:

```
 @media print{
   html, body {
    width: 8.5in;
    height: 11in;
    margin: 0.5in;
    }
    h2:last-child {
     page-break-after:always;
    }
}
```

HTML CODE:

```
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />

  <title>Apple Bavarian Torte</title>
  <script src="modernizr-1.5.js"></script>

  <link href="dwbase.css" rel="stylesheet" />

  <link href="dwlayout.css" rel="stylesheet" media="only screen"/>

 <link href="dweffects.css" rel="stylesheet" media="only screen" />

 <link href="dwprint.css" rel="stylesheet" media="only print" />
```

```
  <header>
     <div id="div1">
        Recipes | Ingredients | Articles <br />
        <input type="search" id="sbox" name="sfield" />
        <input type="button" id="sbutton" value="Search" placeholder="search term" />
     </div>
     <div id="div2">
        Password <br />
        <input type="text" id="pwd" name="pwd" placeholder="password" />
        <input type="button" id="lbutton" value="Log In" />
     </div>
     <div id="div3">
        User Name <br />
        <input type="text" id="user" name="user" placeholder="username" />
     </div>


     <h1>dessertWeb</h1>
     <nav class="horizontal">
        <ul>
           <li><a href="#">recipes</a></li>
           <li><a href="#">menus</a></li>
           <li><a href="#">holidays</a></li>
           <li><a href="#">market</a></li>
           <li><a href="#">shopping</a></li>
           <li><a href="#">columns</a></li>
           <li><a href="#">messages</a></li>
        </ul>
     </nav>

  </header>


  <section id="left">

     <nav class="vertical">
        <h1>Categories</h1>
        <ul>
           <li><a href="#">Cakes</a></li>
           <li><a href="#">Candies</a></li>
           <li><a href="#">Chocolate</a></li>
           <li><a href="#">Cookies</a></li>
           <li><a href="#">Crisps</a></li>
           <li><a href="#">Crumbles</a></li>
           <li><a href="#">Custards</a></li>
           <li><a href="#">Frozen Treats</a></li>
           <li><a href="#">Gelatins</a></li>
           <li><a href="#">Liqueur Desserts</a></li>
           <li><a href="#">Marshmallows</a></li>
           <li><a href="#">Meringues</a></li>
           <li><a href="#">Mousse</a></li>
           <li><a href="#">Pies</a></li>
           <li><a href="#">Pralines</a></li>
           <li><a href="#">Sauces</a></li>
           <li><a href="#">Truffles</a></li>
        </ul>
     </nav>

     <nav class="vertical">
        <h1>Related Recipes</h1>
        <ul>
           <li><a href="#">Apple Crisp</a></li>
           <li><a href="#">Apple Fingers</a></li>
           <li><a href="#">Apple Streudel</a></li>
           <li><a href="#">Cherry Torte</a></li>
           <li><a href="#">Fruit Pie</a></li>
           <li><a href="#">Parfait</a></li>
           <li><a href="#">Strawberry Torte</a></li>
        </ul>
     </nav>

  </section>

  <section id="center">

     <article>
        <hgroup>
           <h1>Apple Bavarian Torte
               <img src="star.png" alt="3 1/2 stars" />
               <img src="star.png" alt="" />
               <img src="star.png" alt=""" />
               <img src="halfstar.png" alt="" />
           </h1>
           <h2>by Lemking</h2>
        </hgroup>

        <img id="dishimg" src="torte.jpg" alt="Torte image" width="250" />
        <p>A classic European torte baked in a springform pan. Cream cheese, 
           sliced almonds, and apples make this the perfect holiday treat 
           (12 servings).
        </p>
        <p><a href="#">Rate/Review</a> | <a href="#">Review Page</a></p>
     </article>

        <aside>
           <h1>Recipe Box</h1>
           <ul>
              <li><a href="#">Add to Recipe Box</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Add to Shopping List</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Share Recipe</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Add to Menu</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Customize Recipe</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Share/Email</a></li>
           </ul>
        </aside>

        <h2>Ingredients</h2>    
        <ul>
           <li>1/2 cup butter</li>
           <li>1/3 cup white sugar</li> 
           <li>1/4 teaspoon vanilla extract</li>
           <li>1 cup all-purpose flour</li> 
           <li>1 (8 ounce) package cream cheese</li>
           <li>1/4 cup white sugar</li>
           <li>1 egg</li>
           <li>1/2 teaspoon vanilla extract</li>
           <li>6 apples - peeled, cored, and sliced</li> 
           <li>1/3 cup white sugar</li> 
           <li>1/2 teaspoon ground cinnamon</li>
           <li>1/4 cup sliced almonds</li>
        </ul>

        <h2>Directions</h2>
        <ol>
           <li>Preheat oven to 450&deg; F (230&deg; C).</li>
           <li>Cream together butter, sugar, vanilla, and flour.</li>
           <li>Press crust mixture into the flat bottom of a 9-inch springform pan. 
               Set aside.</li>
           <li>In a medium bowl, blend cream cheese and sugar. Beat in egg and vanilla.
               Pour cheese mixture over crust.</li>
           <li>Toss apples with sugar and cinnamon. Spread apple 
               mixture over all.</li>
           <li>Bake for 10 minutes. Reduce heat to 400&deg; F (200&deg; C) and continue 
               baking for 25 minutes.</li>
           <li>Sprinkle almonds over top of torte. Continue baking until lightly browned.
               Cool before removing from pan.</li>
        </ol>
  </section>

  <section id="right">

     <h1>Reviews</h1>
     <blockquote>
        <p>
           <img src="star.png" alt="4 stars" /> <img src="star.png" alt="" />
           <img src="star.png" alt="" /> <img src="star.png" alt="" />
        </p>
        <p>I loved the buttery taste of the crust which complements the apples 
           very nicely.</p>
        <p>
           &mdash; Reviewed on Sep. 22, 2014 by MMASON.
        </p>
     </blockquote>

     <blockquote>
        <p>
           <img src="star.png" alt="2 stars" /> <img src="star.png" alt="" />
        </p>
        <p>Nothing special. I like the crust, but there was a little too much 
           of it for my taste, and I liked the filling but there was too little 
           of it. I thought the crunchy apples combined with the sliced almonds 
           detracted from the overall flavor.</p>
        <p>
           &mdash; Reviewed on Sep. 1, 2014 by GLENDACHEF.
        </p>
     </blockquote>


     <blockquote>
        <p>
           <img src="star.png" alt="3 1/2 stars" /> <img src="star.png" alt="" />
           <img src="star.png" alt="" /> <img src="halfstar.png" alt="" />
        </p>
        <p>Delicious!! I recommend microwaving the apples for 3 minutes 
           before baking, to soften them. Great dessert - I'll be making it again 
           for the holidays.</p>
        <p>
           &mdash; Reviewed on August 28, 2014 by BBABS.
        </p>
     </blockquote>
  </section>

  <footer>
      dessertWeb &copy; 2014 English (US)
      <span>
        <a href="#">About</a>
        <a href="#">Developers</a>
        <a href="#">Privacy</a>
        <a href="#">Terms</a>
        <a href="#">Help</a>
      </span>
  </footer>
```

Comment: Can you supply your html please?

I'm guessing it may be in relation to your nesting. So you may need to be a little more specific to the area/elements you're attempting to target.

Comment: @frankstuner I added the code now. I apologize or not adding it initially.

Comment: All good dude. I'm still trying to get my head around your outcome at the moment. Are you attempting the target the very last <h2> in your code? ie: <h2>Directions</h2>

Comment: Are you attempting to achieve this dynamically for a page template? There appears to be potentially variable elements of content I'm seeing ie: the description of the dish, (this could affect the page length). At its most basic I'd start with - #center h2:first-child {}

Comment: H2:last-child means last H2 inside its container, not last child on a printed page.

Comment: @frankstuner yes I am. The thing that is confusing is it is always the first h2 even when not printing I am selecting the h2:last-child and it still chooses the first h2... am I using the h2:last-child wrong?

Comment: @m69 So what would you suggest using then?

Comment: Have a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2051788/css-and-printing-keep-block-of-text-together

Comment: Sadly that example did not help me much as I am not able to edit any of the html and the data can be different. I simply need to break beffore the very last < h2> tag. I used the h2:last-of-type but it breaks on the first and the last one now...getting closer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're looking for is "SECTION > H2:last-of-type", not "H2:last-child", because the OL after the H2 is the last child of their parent.

Answer (score 0):

I had to specifically name the one due to myself not being able to grab the last < h2> so I used this code:

```
 h2:nth-last-child(2) {

page-break-before:always;

 }
```