# Keep h tag with next p tag when wrapping images

Tags: css, joomla, word-wrap

In a Joomla (3.6.5) article I have an image with style: `float:left`, with several *h3* headings, each followed by some plain paragraph text.

Depending on the viewing screen width, which varies a lot, sometimes one of the *h3* headings lines up at the bottom of, but still to the right of, the image and the following paragraph is underneath the image on the left. (see mockups)

What I am trying to achieve is to keep the *h3* heading with the following first paragraph in the same way as MS Word's "keep with next" function.

I have no special CSS for this article and am not using *ul* or *ol* lists. There is only one column and one page, so *page-break-avoid* is not relevant. It is not a page-break issue.

I have tried wrapping the *h3* and associated *p* tags in a container, but that makes no difference.

Image 1: current text wrapping
[image: Image 1: current text wrapping]

Image 2: the 'keep with next' text wrap I am wanting to achieve:
[image: Image 2: the 'keep with next' text wrap I am wanting to achieve]

For what it's worth, the code is just:

```
<h3 style="margin-top: 0; line-height: 30px;">
  <img src="images/image-file.jpg" alt="alt text" style="margin-right: 15px; margin-bottom: 5px; float: left;" />h3 heading
</h3>
<p>Some text<br />Some more text</p>
<h3>Another h3 heading</h3>
<p>The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog</p>
</h3>
<h3>Third h3 heading</h3>
<p>Last bit of text. Would like to keep previous h3 heading with this first line when wrapping around images</p>
```

Any suggestions gratefully received.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CSS and Printing : Keep block of text together](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2051788/css-and-printing-keep-block-of-text-together)

Comment: I don't think it's a duplicate as it's not a page-break issue.

Answer (score 0):

You are heading in the right direction by wrapping the `<h3>` and the associated `<p>` tags in a container, but rather than floating the images left, float these containers right.

Comment: Thanks, Neil. I couldn't get this to work. Wrapping individual groups of h3 and p tagged text into containers with float: right (and removing the image's float: left) just threw those divs off to the left - outside the component area and over the adjacent sidebar, in fact. Wrapping the whole lot - except the image - in a container moved everything under the image. Maybe I'm missing something?

Answer (score 0):

It can be solved with a media query. It's not a general solution, but you can do it with an inline css something like this.

```
<style>
@media (max-width: "500px"){ //Change it accordingly, whenever that break between h3 and p occurs
h3.yourclass{clear: left;} //Assign a class to that h3 or select it with nth-child selector 
}
</style>
```

Comment: Thanks, I got there eventually, after trying about 100 different max-widths. I did, however, remove the double quotes from around the pixels as my Joomla css does not use them in this instance. As you say, it's not a general solution, as it will depend each time on the width of the image used, but it achieves what I was looking for. (I have given you a positive vote but as my reputation is low it doesn't show).

Comment: @Gillian You are able to award this answer with the green tick if it was the most helpful in resolving your issue.