# Text cut at page break when print

Tags: html, css

My text inside a div is cut at page break when trying to print in Chrome. I've tried all kinds of page-break-xxx, as well as `orphans: 5; widows: 5; page-break-after: avoid; page-break-before: avoid;`. I've also tried to set the div to display as table, block, inline, inline-block... but nothing works. I've spent a lot of time googling... I believe this must be answered somewhere... Could anyone point me to a direction as how or where to find the solution? Thanks in advance!
[image]

```
  <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="tab_1">
    {{ product.metafields.a }}
  </div>

  <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="tab_2">
    {{ product.metafields.b }}
  </div>

  <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="tab_3">
    {{ product.metafields.c }}
  </div>
```

The code looks like above. They are actually tabs, and I force them to all show up on print. I've tried all kinds of `page-break-xxx` on `.tab-pane`.

{{ product.metafields.x }} are basically texts like H2, P tags.

Comment: can you post the full code?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CSS Printing: Avoiding cut-in-half DIVs between pages?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/907680/css-printing-avoiding-cut-in-half-divs-between-pages)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know why it didn't work at first... probably used on the wrong element. but just tried again and this fixes the problem
[CSS Printing: Avoiding cut-in-half DIVs between pages?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/907680/css-printing-avoiding-cut-in-half-divs-between-pages?rq=1)

Answer (score 2):

Try adding class to your elements,

for instance.

```
<div class="no-break">
</div>
```

then on your print.css

add this

```
.no-break{ page-break-before: always; }
```

This will allow your page from being uncut.

Comment: thanks for your tip. I tried adding `page-break-before: always` on `.tab-pane` (which is the wrapper around the text), and the text elements inside, but neither is a success.