# How to stop HTML printing from breaking a container element?

Tags: html, printing

I'm dynamically loading HTML from a database, then formatting it and printing it to paper. Many times, the page break is in the middle of a DIV or other container element. How can I format my output so that it doesn't do that?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to create a print stylesheet with a media query to target only print devices.  There is a subset of CSS which can be used to style printed media.  You can find detailed syntax help here.

[CSS Printing: Avoiding cut-in-half DIVs between pages?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/907680/css-printing-avoiding-cut-in-half-divs-between-pages)

Answer (score 0):

the answer was CSS

```
page-break-inside: avoid;
```

used like this:

```
<div style="page-break-inside: avoid;">
  text goes here
</div>
```