# Avoid cutting off words when printing an MVC View

Tags: c#, html, css, razor

I have a page in my MVC application and sometime if the content is long and goes over a page the page will cut off words when going from one page to another. For example here is an example of what I mean. [image: example]

And here is my Grid layout.

```
foreach (Box b in p.uniqueBoxes) {
                if (b.itemList.Count > 0) {
                    bool numshown = false;
                    <div class="grid" style="grid-row:span @b.itemList.Count; grid-column:2;padding:10px">
                        @p.uniqueBoxNumbers(b.identitystring)

                        <br />
                        @Html.Raw("<div class='small noprint'>" + b.packingMaterials + "</div>")

                    </div>
                    int index = 0;
                    while (index < b.itemList.Count) {
                        string s = b.itemList[index];
                        int q = b.itemQuantities[index] * p.boxCountId(b.identitystring);
                        qcount += q;
                        Html.Raw("<tr>");
                        string[] pnd = s.Split(':');
                        <div class="grid" style="grid-column:3;padding:10px">@pnd[0]</div>
                        <div class="grid" style="grid-column:4;padding:10px">@pnd[1]</div>

                        <div class ="grid"style="grid-column:5;padding:10px">@q</div>
                        if (!numshown) {
                            bcount += p.boxCountId(b.identitystring);

                            <div class="grid" style="grid-row:span @b.itemList.Count; grid-column:6;padding:10px">@p.boxCountId(b.identitystring)</div>
                            <div class="grid" style="grid-row:span @b.itemList.Count; grid-column:7;padding:10px">@b.Notes</div>
                            <div class="grid" style="grid-row:span @b.itemList.Count; grid-column:8;padding:10px">@p.weightById(b.identitystring)  lbs</div>
                            <div class="grid-end noprint" style="grid-row:span @b.itemList.Count; grid-column:9;padding:10px" >
                                <div class="dropdown">
                                    <button class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" style="padding:0px 5px 0px 5px;">
                                        Actions
                                    </button>
                                    <div class="dropdown-menu" style="top:25px;left:-135px">
                                        <a class="dropdown-item noprint" href="@b.labelUrl(false, false)" target="label">Print Label</a>
                                        <a class="dropdown-item noprint" href="@b.labelUrl(false, true)" target="label">Print Label (with Pallets)</a>
                                        @Html.ActionLink("Unpack Box", null, new { unpackboxid = b.ID, shippingID = Model.ID, salesOrderID = Model.SalesOrderID }, new { onclick = "return confirm('Are you sure you want to unpack this box?');", @class = "dropdown-item" })
                                        @Html.ActionLink("Serial Numbers", "Serial", new { ID = b.ID }, new { @class = "dropdown-item" })
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            numshown = true;
                        }





                        @Html.Raw("</tr><tr>");

                        index++;
                    }
```

How can I make this page avoid cutting words and other content?

Comment: Have you tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/907680/css-printing-avoiding-cut-in-half-divs-between-pages)?

Comment: I think you should consider updating the tags on this question.  This looks like a print css problem to me rather than an mvc problem.

Comment: @DaveBarnett Yes I have and okay I updated my tags. Thanks!